# Drush Feature Update removing t() and l() function usages

Tags: 7, drush, features

I have a feature that currently has things like this:

```
'body' => '<h3>' . t('Welcome back') . '<span class="fname">%user:field_first_name</span>!</h3>',
```

However, using `drush fu myfeature` generates this:

```
'body' => '<h3>Welcome back<span class="fname">%user:field_first_name</span>!</h3>',
```

Why is this happening? (removal of t() and l() functions).

I did not create this original feature.

Comment: You should show more of the code. We need to understand the context, and a single array index doesn't say much.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a simple as the PHP code being executed? The original feature is created so it supports any language by translating text with the "t" function. However, when the feature is activated, just the text - the executed PHP code - is written to the database (for the given langauge), and you can't ever get back the original PHP code. A feature update will just return the string in the database.

Comment: So you say that it was useless and maybe it was created with an old Features version that used 4() and l()?

Comment: Nothing useless with it in my opinion. At first time activation you get translated output. Afterwards, if you update the feature, you get the current text - nothing wrong with that.